# Retrieve trades executed on FxAll platform using quickfix

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I need to retrieve trades executed on FxAll platform using quickfix. 
I executed a sample trade using the FxALl UI and I have the order id, currency code, party and deal rates available with me.
However I need to get the ccomplete trade details using quick.

I am not sure if it is supported.

I was going through the FxAll documentation and I found the following lines-
FXall sends Execution Report messages to inform the customer of a completed trade on the portal. Only orders that are delivered through FIX will receive an Execution report message.

I need to receive execution report for orders executed using FxAll blotter.

Comment: Hello Manas and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question doesn't really have anything to do with the FIX protocol or QuickFIX. Your question is about FxAll. You are best off asking FxAll support or customer support about these questions.

Comment: HI TT, Yes it looks like FxAll query. But let me rephrase it. If we are executing trades through any UI client and then try to retrieve trades using fix/quick fix, is it possible to retrieve trade details.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about FxAll. If a product advertises that you can, then yes. If that product advertises that you cannot, then you cannot. Really, this is a question you should ask the company that sells the FxAll product. The FIX protocol by itself does not impose restrictions and neither does QuickFIX.